# Invariant violation: View config not found for name

Tags: react-native, createelement

I am getting error in `React-Native` as:

```
Invariant violation: View config not found for name MyCustomComponent.
```

I did search for same error and found that component name's first character should be capitalised which is there in my case.

This is what I am trying to do:
I am trying to load a component using name instead of rendering it directly using `<MyCustomComponent />`

Here is my code:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow' }} >
    {React.createElement('MyCustomComponent', {}, null)}
</View>
```

What can be the issue here. Is there any other way I can load component using string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an `component` and not a `string` to the method

Like

`{React.createElement(MyCustomComponent, {}, null)}`

and not

`{React.createElement('MyCustomComponent', {}, null)}`

String is only for `tags`

Comment: Nopes, It gives error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_props$data.name')

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. I forgot to pass props which were need further in rendering.